# PHP 7.4.10 on CentOS error: unable to locate gmp.h

Tags: php, c, gcc, centos7

I'm using CentOS 7 and building a PHP 7.4.10 rpm from source. We've previously been using PHP 7.2 with gmp located at `/usr/lib64/`, so ./configure in the spec file takes `--with-gmp=/usr/lib64`. This works with no problem, and I've also tested that it still works with PHP 7.3.22. Building PHP 7.4.10 however hits this error: `configure: error: Unable to locate gmp.h`.

```
$ locate gmp.h
/usr/include/gmp.h
```

```
$ locate gmp.so
/usr/lib64/libgmp.so
/usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10
/usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.2.0
```

```
%build
cd %{_builddir}/php-%{version}
export CC=/usr/local/gcc/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/gcc/bin/g++
export CFLAGS="-O3 -m64 -isystem/usr/local/gcc/include -L/usr/local/gcc/lib64 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/gcc/lib64 "
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
./configure --with-gmp=/usr/lib64 --enable-bcmath --enable-ftp --with-curl --with-openssl --enable-mbstring
make -j8
```

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i gmp
gmp-devel-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64
gmp-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64
```

I've tried putting a symlink between `/usr/include/gmp.h` and `/usr/lib64/gmp.h`, which didn't work.
I've also tried adding `-isystem/usr/include` and `-isystem/usr/include/gmp.h`to CFLAGS, CPFLAGS, and CXXFLAGS.

I'm especially baffled since something seems to have changed for PHP 7.4, but I can't find any upgrade notes for it.

Comment: Your include dir seems to be `system/usr/local/gcc/include` rather than `/usr/include`

Answer (score 0):

`--with-gmp=/usr/lib64` searches for the files in `/usr/lib64/include` and `/usr/lib64/lib64`. You need to use `--with-gmp=/usr` or `--with-gmp=shared`.

It's usually quite helpful to consult distribution build scripts when encountering such issues, such as the [PHP 7.4 RPM SPEC file for CentOS](https://git.centos.org/rpms/php/blob/c8s-stream-7.4/f/SPECS/php.spec#_853). Further below, you will see references to `%{_prefix}`, which stands for `/usr`.